# Change the text color in a wx.TextCtrl under Mac or Linux

Tags: linux, wxpython, richtextbox, wxwidgets, textctrl

I am looking for a widget under wx that is similar to TextCtrl with the capabilities to show rich content under Linux and Mac (e.g. different text colors in different lines). I know that wx.TextCtrl with wx.TE_RICH style (or wx.RichTextCtrl) only works under Windows, and not under Mac and Linux.

I have also checked stc.StyledTextCtrl which seems to have the desired capability, given a schema for coloring, so it is mainly used for syntax highlighting. So, I doubt that it works.

So, I was wondering if there is a text box widget TB for wx with an API like:

```
TB.AppendText("Hello, this is Black", wx.BLACK)
TB.AppendText(" and this is Blue", wx.BLUE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, what gave you that idea? The rich text flag for the wx.TextCtrl works fine on Linux for me. I'm using wxPython 2.8.12.0. You may have to use wx.TE_RICH2 though. I was testing using the wxPython demo to see if it worked and it does.

The RichText control in wx.richtext also works as does the FancyText and StyleTextCtrls. I am testing on CentOS 6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The description for wx.TextCtrl (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtextctrl.html) mentions that wx.TE_RICH and wx.TE_RICH2 styles are ignored under platforms other than Win32. I also tried using wx.TE_RICH and wx.TE_RICH2 in my code that runs under Mac, but the texts were not colored differently.

Comment: stc.StyledTextCtrl does work under Mac, but it seems to require a schema for coloring and it has no API to color a text as it is being appended.

Comment: Have you looked at the wxPython demo to see if any of those widgets work on Mac? I don't have a Mac to test with.